# Apply xaml style for FolderBrowserDialog in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles, folderbrowserdialog

I have a style Xaml which I use for styling my WPF windows. But the same style won't get applied for the FolderBrowseDialog which I use in my windows. This gives a weird UI difference between the actual windows and the dialog pop-ups. How to get this corrected?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know unfortunately you cannot. Either you have to create your own user control or use some of the already defined in the internet.

One cool with a lot of other fancy controls is in [Kevin Moore's Bag-o-Tricks](http://work.j832.com/2008/03/bag-o-tricks-march-edition.html).